# Android - How to adjust a popup when the soft keyboard shows up

Tags: android, popup, soft-keyboard, adjustment

[image: without soft keyboard]

[image: when soft keyboard shows up]

I want to replicate this effect in my layout. But in my layout when the keyboard show up, my pop-up is not adjusted. 
The device adjust me the main activity below and not the popup.

this is my popup layout.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sfondo_semi_trasparente_scuro">




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">





    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textNomeGiocatoreNewTeam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Nome giocatore"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textNumeroMagliaGiocatoreNewTeam"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Numero Maglia"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConfirmAddNewPlayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aggiungi giocatore"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to use :  popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

Comment: I use it.. If i don't use it, the keyoboard don't shows up when i click in the EditText..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try instead this:
`popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Comment: It helps me :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    </activity>
```